# Flutter / Auto_route: Can I redirect user back to path/url they intended to visit?

Tags: flutter

We are building out an app with flutter that is intended for both built apps (ios / android) and web.

We are using the auto_route package for routing.

As it stands I have this code in my `MaterialApp.router`:

```
routerDelegate: AutoRouterDelegate.declarative(
        _appRouter,
        routes: (_) => [

          if (_authState.condition == AuthCondition.authenticated)
            ProtectedRouter(children: [MarketplaceScreen()])
          else
            PublicWrapper(children: [SignInRoute()])
        ],
      ),
      routeInformationParser:
          _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(includePrefixMatches: true),
```

Right now this works perfectly. Upon sign in, the user is redirected to the marketplace screen, and if the user is no longer authenticated, it routes the user back to sign in.

My problem is currently confined to web builds, but will also be an issue when you implement deep links on the built apps (I assume)

However, it only goes to the marketplace. If I am on another screen, and refresh the browser for example, I will go back to the marketplace screen.

Is there a way to add in the current location I have (the url in my address bar), and redirect the user back to that instead with marketplace as fallback if nothing matches? This then also when I enter a specific url and hit enter?

Obvious note: I'm quite new to flutter. I have tried to find solutions already, and have read most of auto_route documentation but either misread it, or I don't know what questions to ask.

I have tried to explore the route context too, but struggling to find an option that matches my needs. It's very possible that I looked at it wrong or misunderstand a concept though.